# Imageview to VideoView using fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app with navigation drawer using fragment, where on the home screen there should be images and when you click the image it should take you to that particular image's fragment and video starts playing. But unfortunately I can't see any image on the home screen (maybe I am making mistake in layout). Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Code below :-

main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      tools:context="com.hangout.google.heedbasketball.MainActivity"
      tools:openDrawer="start"
      tools:deviceIds= "tv"
      tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">



      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          android:elevation="4dp"/>

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/i1"
          android:src="@drawable/arena_reaction"/>

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/i2"
          android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_diop"/>

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/i3"
          android:src="@drawable/frequentflyer_tyus"/>

      <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/fragement_container" />




  </LinearLayout>

      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:id="@+id/nav_view"
          app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
          app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>



  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main java file

```
package com.hangout.google.heedbasketball;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

abstract class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this );


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                (this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_sound:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new SoundFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new NotificationsFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_sponsors:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new SponsorsFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new AboutFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_contact_us:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new ContactusFragment()).commit();

                break;

            case R.id.nav_privacy:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new PrivacyFragment()).commit();

                break;

        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new FirstFragment()).commit();
                    fragment = new FirstFragment();
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new SecondFragment()).commit();
                    fragment = new SecondFragment();

                case 2:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container,new ThirdFragment()).commit();
                    fragment = new ThirdFragment();

                    break;

                default:
                    fragment = new FirstFragment();
            }

            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;

        }
    }
    public void onBackpressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            onBackPressed();
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the java fragment for one video I have defined in the same way for other videos too

```
package com.hangout.google.heedbasketball;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.VideoView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FirstFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FirstFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

//My video code here
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            VideoView v1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.v1);
            v1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://myvideo.mp4"));
            v1.start();
            v1.requestFocus();
            v1.setKeepScreenOn(true);


        }
    }

    private Object findViewById(int v1) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


        }

xml file fragment for the video

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/v1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can I know, why have you suggested to edit almost all the files, except fragments??

Answer (score 0):

You have created findViewById function in on create which returns 0.

You need a video reference from layout which you are inflating.
Something similar to this.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        // see the difference
        VideoView v1 = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.v1);
        v1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://myvideo.mp4"));
        v1.start();
        v1.requestFocus();
        v1.setKeepScreenOn(true);    
     return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried with your way but now I my app can't even open.